# Generate correlated categorical (non ordinal) data

Tags: r, simulate, categorical-data

I tried with the OrdGen package this way :

```
    marginal <-list(0.8,c(0.2,0.4),c(0.15,0.15,0.4)) # proba marginales
    corrcheck(marginal)             # Checks the lower and upper bounds of the correlation coefficients.
                # pas possible de définir des corrélations hors ces bornes avec ces marginales
    R <- matrix(c(1,0.3,0.3,0.3,1,0.3,0.3,0.3,1),3,3,byrow=T) # Correlation matrix
    n <- 100
    m <- ordsample(n=n, marginal=marginal, Sigma=R)
```

But I get this error message

### Error message :

Error in cut.default(valori[, i], breaks = c(min(valori[, i]) - 1, qnorm(marginal[[i]]),  : 
  'breaks' are not unique
Calls: ordsample -> cut -> cut.default

I Guess it has something to do with the link between the marginal and the "correlation" matrix, maybe it comes from the fact that the categorical data I want to simulate isn't ordinal, so linear correlation proposed can be broken by non ordered categories ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug : 
The marginal probabilities are supposed to be cumulative :

```
    marginal <-list(0.8,c(0.2,0.4),c(0.15,0.15,0.4)
```

should be

```
    marginal <-list(0.8,c(0.2,0.6),c(0.15,0.3,0.7)
```

Sorry for the useless post. I leave the answer as it may help people wishing to generate categorical data.